# NSData method mutableCopy() does not work as objC [... mutableCopy]?

Tags: swift

Swift 4:

```
let d1 = NSData(base64Encoded: "wAEP/w==")!
let d2 = d1.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableData
```

d1 and d2 points to the same address in memory, however I would expect that mutableCopy() will work as objC [d1 mutableCopy] - eg. create new instance of NSMutableData object.

Do I really do something wrong, or Swift works differently?

Comment: Why are you using `NSData` and `NSMutableData` in Swift? Just use `Data` with `let` or `var` as needed.

Comment: @rmaddy This is an example I want to understand.

Comment: Why do you think `d1` and `d2` point to the same address? If you modify the mutable data using `d2`, the value in `d1` isn't affected.

Comment: How did you obtain/compare the addresses?

Comment: I use Swift Playgrounds. This example is from Advanced Swift book where is written: "If we copy a struct variable, a shallow copy is made. This means the reference to the NSMutableData object, and not the object itself, will get copied." That is nice, but I do not understand why.

Comment: I have to think about the example again, however it works as in objc - probably copy-on-write makes it more fuzzy for me.

Comment: @MichaelBernat `NSData` is not a struct, but a class in Swift, `Data` is a struct however

Comment: @DávidPásztor the book is correct, but the sentence is related to another struct - my incorrect understanding of the example.

Answer (score 2):

No, `d1` and `d2` are not pointing to the same address in memory. And it is creating a different instance.

What you are seeing on the right of the playground isn't the address of the object, it's the representation of the `Data` you have. To prove it's creating a different instance, just try this code:

```
let d1 = NSData(base64Encoded: "wAEP/w==")!
let d2 = d1.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableData
d2.append(Data(base64Encoded: "wAEP")!)
print(d1)
print(d2)
```

If they were the same instance, `d2` would print the same as `d1`

Comment: Thanks, I have just discovered it too - once data is changed, copy-on-write changes the address of the data buffer of d2.

Comment: I think you are confused. Copy-on-write are only implemented in Swift to native value-types. NSData and NSMutableData are classes. If you check the address in memory after they're created, they are different...